# Google map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map API to show users position on map. When I click marker on google-map  pop fragment under screen such like original goolglemap

How can I use `onMarkerclickListener`

This is my code:

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // 구글 맵 객체를 불러온다.
    mMap = googleMap; //메인 마커

    // 초기 위치 설정
    LatLng seoul = new LatLng(37.56, 126.97);   
    MarkerOptions makerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    makerOptions.position(seoul)
            .title("서울")
            .snippet("포토존")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.point));

    // 마커를 생성한다.
    mMap.addMarker(makerOptions);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(seoul)); //카메라 위치 이동
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10)); //카메라줌

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    /*Toast.makeText(this, marker.getTitle()+"\n"+marker.getPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `onMarkerClick` method like this:

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // 구글 맵 객체를 불러온다.
    mMap = googleMap; //메인 마커

    // 초기 위치 설정
    LatLng seoul = new LatLng(37.56, 126.97);
    MarkerOptions makerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    makerOptions.position(seoul)
            .title("서울")
            .snippet("포토존")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.point));

    // 마커를 생성한다.
    mMap.addMarker(makerOptions);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(seoul)); //카메라 위치 이동
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10)); //카메라줌

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            //Do what ever you need here
            //Note:  the return value depends on how you wish to handler the clicks on the Marker
            // See Google Docs for more information
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: @dona :: Have you had an opportunity to look at this answer?